# Android ToggleButton - do something while enabled without locking up UI thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, togglebutton

What I want to do is run a method that will play a random sound from my assets while a ToggleButton is On. And then stop doing that when the ToggleButton is Off. The problem is that as currently constructed, my code locks up with UI thread. I thought I was using AsyncTask correctly, but apparently not.

Can you suggest either a fix for this or a better method to accomplish what I want?

```
    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();



    while (on) {

        AssetManager assetMgr = this.getAssets();
        try {
            String[] filename = assetMgr.list("sounds");
            Random r = new Random();
            String fn = filename[r.nextInt(filename.length)];
            if (MyService.mp.isPlaying()) {

            }
            else {

                new PlayShuffleMode().execute(fn);

        }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And here is the AsyncTask method:

```
private class PlayShuffleMode extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... fn) {

        mService.playfav(fn[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `while` loop. The `while` loop will loop continuously on the main thread until you toggle the button, but since the `while` loop is on the main thread, your UI will get locked up. So you must figure out a way to move the `while` loop into your AsyncTask.

One suggestion: Instead of having the AsyncTask inside of the while loop, why not do the inverse and have the while loop in the AsycTask? Something like...

```
private playShuffle;

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
  ToggleButton tb = ((ToggleButton) view);
  tb.setChecked(!tb.isChecked()); // Toggle the state.

  if(tb.isChecked()) {
    playShuffle = new PlayShuffleMode();
    playShuffle.execute();
  }
  else {
    playShuffle.cancel();
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I check that the ToggleButton is still on from the AsyncTask? The code above would just run the AsyncTask once (after turning on the toggle button).

Comment: Thanks. This is getting me in the right direction. At the moment, I can't figure out how to check the state of the ToggleButton from inside the AsyncTask. It looks like I'll need to pass the state and maybe I can check it in the onPostExecute() method.

Comment: You dont have to check the status in the AsyncTask. When you click the toggle button `onToggleClicked()` is called and checks the state of the ToggleButton. If it is on, create the AsyncTask, cache it, and execute it. It will play forever until `onToggleClicked()` is pressed again. If the status is off, take the cached AsyncTask and call `cancel()` to cancel the task which will end the playback. I edited the code above to make it more clear.